# How do I create an alias for a program on the desktop of multiple users? Mac OSX

Tags: macos, desktop

I would like to create an alias on the desktop for FileMaker. I need this alias to show up on each user's desktop on this Mac. We do not use Mac OS X Server. There are just several users on one machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a simple bash script to create symbolic links e.g.

```
for d in /Users/* ; do 
    sudo ln -fs /Applications/Filemaker.app $d/Desktop/Filemaker.app
done
```

Comment: This looks like it will work for all users that are already under the /Users/ directory. What if a domain user had not logged into the computer yet? will this have to be run again?

Comment: To make it available for users that don't have a home folder yet, add it to the user template: `sudo ln -fs /Applications/Filemaker.app /System/Library/User\ Template/English.lproj/Desktop/Filemaker.app`